# Python sockets: [Errno 99] when binding to ip on local network

Tags: python, sockets, networking, udp

I am trying to set up a UDP unicast between two linux-machines on my local network, using the python sockets library. I manage to send and receive the package using the following code:

**Send**

```
import socket

HOST = '192.168.1.194' # IP of remote machine
PORT = 47808

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.sendto('Hello UDP', (HOST, PORT))
s.close()
```

**Receive**

```
import socket

HOST = ''
PORT = 47808

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
while True:
    try:
        data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
        print 'Received: {0} @ {1}'.format(data, addr)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
s.close()
```

However, binding to `''` makes the receiving code accept packets from any local interface. If I try to bind to the IP address of the sending machine specifically (changing `HOST = ''`to `HOST = '192.168.1.130'` in the receiving code), I get a `socket.error: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address`. No other services are using the port, and I have tried different ports with no change in behaviour. How can I configure my socket to only receive packets from a specific address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's deal with the error you are seeing. `.bind()` names the *local* end of the socket, not the remote. So the host part must refer to the local machine (e.g., `'localhost'`, `'127.0.0.1`, `'192.168.1.194'`, or `''` (wildcard for all local interfaces).) So, when you specify an address that isn't local to the machine running `.bind()`, you get an error.

Second, there is no way to "configure my socket to only receive packets from a specific address." As an alternative, you can use the returned address from `.recvfrom()` to ignore data you don't care about.

```
data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
if addr != '192.168.1.130':
    continue
```